# Getting value of EditText contained in a Custom Dialog Box

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

So I have made a custom Dialog Box in my app that contains a EditText field specifically formatted for numbers. I have the code set up to launch the Dialog when the user clicks a button. The issue I'm having is that when the user confirms the information they've entered, I'm getting a error like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Here is the complete code for my Dialog Box inflater and the button click handlers.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        Log.i("INFO","Creating Dialog...");

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.goaldialog, null))
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.SetAGoalButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.GoalChooser);
                        Integer goalNumber = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                        Log.i("INFO",Integer.toString(goalNumber));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
        return builder.create();
    }
```

I'm new to android and Java, so help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** intrepidkarthi's answer solved my initial problem, but now the string that is getting returned looks like this:

```
07-22 14:13:43.687  29972-29972/com.collusion.serviceassistant D/INFO﹕ [ 07-22 14:13:43.687 29972:29972 D/AndroidRuntime ]
    Shutting down VM
```

I'm getting the text from EditText using this:

```
String goalNumberString = String.valueOf(et.getText());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    Log.i("INFO","Creating Dialog...");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.goaldialog, null);
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(view)
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.SetAGoalButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText et = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.GoalChooser);
                    Integer goalNumber = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    globalVariable = goalNumber;
                    Log.i("INFO",Integer.toString(goalNumber));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.show();
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just have to wait

Comment: Now I have a weird problem. The returned value from the EditText is this: 07-22 14:11:01.649  28038-28038/com.collusion.serviceassistant I/INFO﹕ [ 07-22 14:11:01.649 28038:28038 D/AndroidRuntime ].


I'm getting the value using: String goalNumberString = String.valueOf(et.getText());

Comment: Update the complete log in the question itself

Comment: Are you trying to get the `String` once after you dismiss the `dialog`?

Comment: have a global variable to get the value stored.

Comment: I'm new to Java, how do I declare a global variable?

Comment: Declare the `int` at the beginning of your `Activity` or 'Fragment'

Comment: So in the onCreate method?

Comment: above and outside that method

Comment: It says that it is a Non-static field and cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Understand what is going on first. Check `Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString())` line, add a condition before this to check 'EditText' string length

Comment: Its returning a length of 0

Comment: Is it possible that an EditText box set to number format returns an Integer?

Comment: No. You have to typecast it

Comment: So using the following code is still not returning what I entered, even though it doesn't crash: Main.etText = String.valueOf(et.getText().toString());
                        Log.i("Der", etText);

Answer (score 0):

capture the View instance into a variable when you use setView(), then you can use findViewById to get the EditText:

```
final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.goaldialog, null);
builder.setView(view)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.SetAGoalButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText et = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.GoalChooser);
                    Integer goalNumber = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    Log.i("INFO",Integer.toString(goalNumber));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong instruction:

```
EditText et = (EditText)onCreateDialog().findViewById(R.id.GoalChooser);
```

Example:

```
mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String content = mEdit.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  EditText et = (EditText)onCreateDialog().findViewById(R.id.GoalChooser);
```

Put that in here like this:

```
  public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
      final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.GoalChooser);
```

does it work? im just guessing, the problem is your EditText is null since you are referencing in from another context (you are not using the context of the activity to instantiate that edit text).

Answer (score 0):

when we use inflater.inflate from a layout xml file,we need to add the view before findViewById。

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.goaldialog, null);
```

EditText et = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.GoalChooser);